# String matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get column names from SQL 'CREATE' query.

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE 'test' (
'col1' INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
'col2' VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
'col3' DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

**Code:**

```
preg_match_all("/'(.+)' (\w+)\(? ?(\d*) ?\)?/", $sql, $_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 'col1\' INT( 10 ) [1] => col1\ [2] => INT [3] => 10 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 'col2\' VARCHAR( 50 ) [1] => col2\ [2] => VARCHAR [3] => 50 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 'col3\' DATE [1] => col3\ [2] => DATE [3] => ) 
)
```

But I need simple result like this:

```
array(
  array('INT( 10 )', 'col1'),
  array('VARCHAR( 50 )', 'col2'),
  array('DATE', 'col3')
);
```

Every possible solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related Answer: [How to fetch column names from 'MySQL Create Table' Query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590928/how-to-fetch-column-names-from-mysql-create-table-query-string/5591342#5591342)

Comment: looks like a problem with `addslashes()` or `magic_quotes` (before `preg_match_all`)

Comment: @hakre: I asked this question. I need a better solution. Read this question..

Comment: My php is very rusty, but couldn't you do a simple query, then use the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function and loop it using `foreach` and get the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = <<<SQL
       CREATE TABLE 'test' (
       'col1' INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
       'col2' VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
       'col3' DATE NOT NULL
       ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
SQL;

preg_match_all("/'(.+)' (\w+(?:\( ?\d* ?\))?)/", $sql, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$matches = array_map(function($array) {
  return array($array[2], $array[1]);
}, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "INT( 10 )"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "col1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "VARCHAR( 50 )"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "col2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "col3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-using the existing query from the previous answer:

```
preg_match_all("/'(.+)' ((\w+)\(? ?(\d*) ?\)?)/", $sql, $_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$matches = array_map(function($v) {return array(trim($v[2]), $v[1]);}, $_matches);
```