# Closure causes syntax error in php-5.2

Tags: php, closures, php-5.2

I am executing following code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404023/string-matching):

```
preg_match_all("/'(.+)' ((\w+)\(? ?(\d*) ?\)?)/", $sql, $_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$matches = array_map(function($v) {return array(trim($v[2]), $v[1]);}, $_matches);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in SqlParser.php on line 29
```

I have spent some time to solve this but I am unable to find the solution.

Can someone tell me that what is wrong ?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897496/making-a-php-closure-function-safe-for-php-5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a PHP version less than 5.3, which does not support closures (You confirmed this in your comments).  The code below should work. I just converted the anonymous function to a normal function.

```
function map_cb($v){
    return array(trim($v[2]), $v[1]);
}


preg_match_all("/'(.+)' ((\w+)\(? ?(\d*) ?\)?)/", $sql, $_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$matches = array_map("map_cb", $_matches);
```

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10

Comment: It tried it and it is giving me following error: `Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, 'map_cb', should be either NULL or a valid callback`

Comment: Are you sure you cut and pasted all the code including the map_cb function?

Comment: yes, I am coding it in `class` so I just put `public` before `map_cb `function.

Comment: Then you have to use array($this,"map_cb") instead of "map_cb"

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using php 5.3, you can't use an anonymous function like that.  According to [the php documentation for callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback),

> As of PHP 5.3.0 it is possible to also
>   pass a closure to a callback
>   parameter.

You can use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) instead to create anon. functions, and that will work pre-PHP 5.3.  Or use GWW's answer, that should work too.

Otherwise, if you're interested in learning more about anon. functions in PHP 5.3+, you can read [their php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.10

Comment: @Awan then that's you're problem.  I think you can use something like `create_function()` instead then.  Or use @GWW suggestion, that should work too.