# Making a PHP closure function safe for PHP 5.2

Tags: php, closures, php-5.2

The following function works in PHP > 5.3 but errors out in older versions. How can I modify this to make it 5.2 safe?

```
function _iniloader_get_dirs($dir) {
        $dirs = array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($item) use ($dir) {
            return (is_dir($dir.'/'.$item) && $item != "." && $item != "..");
        });
        // Use array_values to reset the array keys:
        return array_values($dirs);
}
```

**5.2 error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION ... on
>   line 2

Comment: PHP 5.3 came out three years ago, and 5.2 is no longer supported. Is it absolutely necessary to support it?

Comment: Our hosting platform uses it for WordPress.

Comment: I'd get a new hosting platform. Using unsupported versions of PHP exposes you to significant security risks.

Comment: ceejayoz- not an option. Besides, we're planning to release it as a wp plugin, and 75% of sites are still using 5.2, only 20% use 5.3

Comment: Is getting your server hacked an option?

Comment: ? We're not going to deny people the right to use the majority version . We're operating in a real world environment.

Comment: Not supporting old versions in something people want to use is a good way to get them to upgrade (or complain to their hosting companies to upgrade)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it w/o the closure, but you will lose some elegance:

```
function _iniloader_get_dirs($dir) {
    $dirs = array();
    $entries = scandir($dir);
    foreach($entries as $item) {
        if($item === '.' || $item === '..') continue;
        if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$item)) continue;
        $dirs[] = $item;
    }
    return $dirs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally the way to mimic closures in PHP<5.3 is with [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) but because of the `use` clause in this case, I can't come up with a way to do it without doing something horrible involving bouncing variables through the global scope. There may be something I'm missing.

In any case, here is some code that will do the same thing without requiring a closure:

```
function _iniloader_get_dirs($dir) {
    $dirs = array();
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$item) && !in_array($item, array('.', '..'))) {
            $dirs[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $dirs;
}
```

Comment: DaveRandom- Thanks, this works too- Gave it to DerVO as he was quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (untested). The idea is to insert the value of $dir into the source of the function.

```
function _iniloader_get_dirs($dir) {
    $dirs = array_filter(scandir($dir),
        create_function('$item', '$dir = \'' . $dir . '\';' .
            'return (is_dir($dir."/".$item) && $item != "." && $item != "..");'));
    return array_values($dirs);
}
```

Beware if you call this function a lot, because every time `create_function` is called, it creates a new function in the program memory that stays forever, even if it is essentially the same as other functions except a variable. So if you call this a lot then the program will be filled with dummy functions and run out of memory.